# Paypal monthly recurring payment: Minimal for 12 months - possible?

Tags: time, paypal, payment, minimum, recurring

I can not find a useful answer on paypals website.

Is it possible to install a monthly recurring payment for my customers, that has a minimum of 12 payments (1 ever month)? So that the customer can not cancel the recurring payment after for example 3 months?
I want to offer a monthly plan for my customers, a plan that is cheaper if they agree to pay for 12 months. And I do not want to charge them the full yearly amount at one time. 12 times only 10$ sounds better than paying 120$ at once.
Is paypal useful for that kind of payment?
Or can the customer close his account for example?

Thank you
  Bodo

Comment: PayPal recurring payments and subscriptions can be cancelled. You want an installment payments plan, which is different. PayPal supports certain types of installment plans in some geographies (e.g. Brazil), but does not have support for installment payments across all geographies.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no API method which not allow customer to cancel the recurring payment! For your specific case recommended to use paypal express checkout API, but this is just a way to implement your idea - When create a recurring payment you have option to charge user two times - one is related with INITAMT parameter and this get charged immediately from user account. Second is related with BILLINGPERIOD, BILLINGFREQUENCY, TOTALBILLINGCYCLES and REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES paypal parameters, which is related with recurring payment **AFTER** current period of time. The key is to set a payment after the recurring period of time and set a INITAMT to get first payment immediately - in your case this will be a sum of first three month.

For (PHP) example :

```
$padata['BILLINGPERIOD']                    = 'Month';
$padata['BILLINGFREQUENCY']                 = '1';
$padata['TOTALBILLINGCYCLES']               = '12';
$padata['REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES']        = '1';
$padata['INITAMT']                          = 'sum of first three month';
```